# using jquery json to get youtube video title

Tags: jquery, json, api, youtube

I am trying to get the media:title element from a youtube user's feed using jquery's get json method. I can get a number of the other nodes successfully, but I can't get the media title. Here's the feed url:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/armaniexchange/uploads?alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=showMyVideos
```

And here's the code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/armaniexchange/uploads?alt=json-in-script&callback=?&max-results=2', function(data) { 
        $.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item) {
                var updated = item.updated;
                var url = item['media$group']['media$content'][0]['url'];
                var thumb = item['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][0]['url'];
        var media_title = item['media$group']['media$title'];
                var numViews = item['yt$statistics']['viewCount'];

        //$('#feed_container').append('<div class="thumb"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-link="' + url + '">' + media_title + '</a></div>');

                alert([url, thumb, numViews,media_title].join('\n')); // display it
        });



});
});
```

Comment: Tip: accept some answers. Both of your previous questions received at least one working solution.

Comment: Agreed, please accept my answer if it works for you, thank you... and an upvote doesn't hurt either. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `media_title` is an object that contains the properties `$t` with the title you want and another property `type` with a purpose unknown to me.

I've **[created a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FzejW/)** to call `media_title.$t` to show the title you want.